# Moving a web application from one domain to a new domain Flash/Actionscript/Php/MySql

Tags: php, flash, actionscript

I have moved a web application from old domain to new domain.
I cannot get Flash to engage.
I have changed the domain in flash_images.php file to the new domain.
I have a flash_box.swf file and I have a js file these are the only flash components that I see--old domain is e.g. `www.example.com` new domain is `www.example2.com`
I am not a flash developer, how do I get flash to work on the new domain?

Answer (score 0):

The flash on your new site is working, however it's not pulling the images correctly. The best bet is probably to check the naming and nesting of your domain's file space; it should be identical (capitalization, extensions) to the structure on your old domain and make sure you have all the image files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed all of the HTML, PHP references in any absolute links to the old domain, barring any internal links embedded in the SWF that are hard-coded to the old domain, this should work just fine.

However if there are absolute links embedded in the SWF, you're going to have to change the actionscript/flex code internally and then recompile.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just agree with the previous answers - the SWF will not care at all what domain it exists in. If it contains any dynamically loaded assets (images, sounds, xml, etc), pathing must be perfect. Normally, we use relative linkage to ensure this, but if absolute paths are use, a new domain will bork the whole system. You will need to go into the flash file and ensure any external requests use correct paths.